# php file includes with files in different directories

Tags: php, directory, include

I am currently trying to include a file into another file, they are in two separate directories in a structure that looks like this.

```
public_html
     \includes
         \check_login_status.php
         \db_connect.php
      \users
          \users.php
```

I want to include `check_login_status.php` into `user.php`.

I am doing this to include it `include_once("/public_html/includes/check_login_status.php");`

I feel like this should work, but all the variables that depend on the include are returning null when debugging. Is there another way to include a files from a directory on the same level as the directory you are in?

**check_login_status.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("/db_connnect.php");
// Files that inculde this file at the very top would NOT require 
// connection to database or session_start(), be careful.
// Initialize some vars
$user_ok = false;
$log_id = "";
$log_username = "";
$log_password = "";
// User Verify function
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])) {
    $log_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_SESSION['userid']);
    $log_username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['username']);
    $log_password = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['password']);
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_connect,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
} else if(isset($_COOKIE["id"]) && isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["pass"])){
    $_SESSION['userid'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_COOKIE['id']);
    $_SESSION['username'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
    $_SESSION['password'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['pass']);
    $log_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $log_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $log_password = $_SESSION['password'];
    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = evalLoggedUser($db_connect,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
    if($user_ok == true){
        // Update their lastlogin datetime field
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$log_id' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_connnect, $sql);
    }
}
?>
```

**db_connect.php**

```
<?php
$db_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "formfitdata", "**********", "formfit_users");
//check if connection error
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
include_once("../includes/check_login_status.php");
```

It's possible that public_html is not in the root folder of the server.

Comment: I tried this, and the variables are still returning null during debugging.

Comment: I think then the error is not in the include but rather in the target file. If you try require_once, does it return an error? If not, the include is working and it must be something in the code.

Comment: require once, does not return an error, but the file is included in other files in the same directory and it performs its functions properly. For some reason the variables are returning null.

Comment: If I think of something I will let you know

Comment: If you could give us a little bit of code, for example have you tried debugging the variables in the check_login_status.php, and making sure they are not null? etc etc.

Comment: @DavidWolters I added the check login status, and db_connect.php, gthe variable returning null is $db_connect

Comment: What if you do instead of "/db_connect" simply write "db_connect", that is emit the forward slash

Comment: this worked, i understand why it does, but i don't understand why it wasn't working. I copied all the code, deleted it, and repasted it in frustration and it worked. Im not complaining

Comment: Great news, glad it helped although it is kind of strange :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// users.php
include_once __DIR__ ."/../includes/check_login_status.php"
```

Try to make it an absolute path using magic constant [__DIR__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Relative paths will be evaluated relative to the calling script; if you - for example - include users.php within an index.php it could lead to unexpected behaviour:

E.g.

```
public_html
  index.php // include "/users/users.php"
  \includes
    check_login_status.php
  \users
    users.php // include "../includes/check_login_status.php"
```

Will make index.php include from "public_html/../includes/check_login..." which does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for might be:

```
include "/path/to/my/file.php";
```